# How to mock a RestTemplate proxy call?

Tags: java, spring, testing, proxy, resttemplate

I have an integration test that correctly mocks an auth call, but it needs to support a proxy now. I'm inexperienced with proxies and am having a great deal of trouble testing this.

The implementation is as follows:

```
proxySettings.setProxy(httpClientBuilder, null);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
    new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClientBuilder.build()));

...

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, type);
```

The `setProxy()` method fetches some user configured proxy settings and applies them to the `HttpClientBuilder`:

```
//Fetch user-configured proxy settings and null check before returning object
HttpHost proxyHttpHost = getHttpClientProxyHttpHost();

httpClientBuilder.setProxy(proxyHttpHost);

//If user/pass is set (credentialsProvider is just a new instance of BasicCredentialsProvider)
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(getHttpProxyHost(), Integer.parseInt(getHttpProxyPort())),
    proxyUsernamePasswordCredentials
);
httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

A non-proxy version of the test passes with this expectation:

```
expect().when(
    request()
        .withMethod("POST")
        .withPath("/auth")
        .withBody(
            params(
                param("client_id", clientId),
                param("client_secret", clientSecret),
                param("grant_type", grantType),
                param("scope", scope)
            ))
).respond(
    response()
        .withStatusCode(expectedResponseStatusCode)
        .withContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .withBody(json("{\"access_token\":\"ImAHappyString\"}"))
);
```

When I run the test with the proxy configured (host: `proxy-host.com`, port: `1234`) I get the following error:

```
ErrorMessage: I/O error on POST request for "http://127.0.0.1:37351/auth": proxy-host.com: Name or service not known; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy-host.com: Name or service not known
```

I tried expecting a `CONNECT` request, but I just get the same failure. Any suggestions?